# Unable to load netCDF data into python

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

I am trying to open three netCDF files into a Python script. I was able to successfully load two of them into 2D NumPy arrays, but the third is causing issues. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset

# loading data
rootgrp1 = Dataset("file_1.nc", "r", format="NETCDF4")
rootgrp2 = Dataset("file_2.nc", "r", format="NETCDF4")
rootgrp3 = Dataset("file_3.nc", "r", format="NETCDF4")

# put values into numpy arrays
data1 = np.array(rootgrp1.variables['RAW' ][:, :].data)
data2 = np.array(rootgrp2.variables['RAW' ][:, :].data)
data3 = np.array(rootgrp3.variables['TEMP'][:, :].data)
```

The last line throws this error: `TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')`

I think that the problem is that the data is not in its own valid range. When I inspect the data using a different application, the numbers are in the 2000s, sometimes 3000s. However, when I look at the `valid_range` attribute for the `Dataset` object, it is 0 to 330:

[image: Valid range for rootgrp3]

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question seems tough to answer without something to reproduce the issue.  Are you able to share any of the files or snippets of the problematic data (though please don't share anything sensitive)?  If you could generate a tiny test file to reproduce the issue and share that, it would go a long way toward getting you a solution I think.

Comment: what does the data3 line produce without the np.array wrapper?

Comment: The error says something is trying to do a multiply on string data.  I don't see a multiply in your code.  What does the error traceback show?

Comment: @hpaulj Without the `np.array` wrapper, it produces a `np.ndarray`, which I now realize will also be okay -- I'll remove the wrappers. Here's a pastebin for the error traceback: https://pastebin.com/HTxqrDTM

Answer (score 0):

That is because netcdf auto scale the data before casting the data to `np.ndarray`. You can avoid this by calling `rootgrp1['RAW' ].set_auto_scale(False)`. After that you can just get the `raw` data values.